# strftime() and gmstrftime() return wrong results for "%s"

Tags: php

PHP Functions `strftime()` and `gmstrftime()` return (different) wrong results for format `"%s"`. I tested it with PHP 5.5.14 and PHP 7.2.5, both with CLI and Apache (OpenSuse). I used timestamps with and without DST.

**My question: Can you confirm the bug with other versions/systems?**

## Test Script

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$list = array(
    1546303600, // 2018-01-01 00:46:40 UTC
    1556703600, // 2019-05-01 09:40:00 UTC
);

echo "\ndate_default_timezone_set('UTC')\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

foreach ( $list as $time )
{
    printf("\n%u\n%4s\n%s\n",
        $time,
        strftime('%s, %F %T %Z',$time),
        gmstrftime('%s, %F %T %Z',$time) );
}

echo "\ndate_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin')\n";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

foreach ( $list as $time )
{
    printf("\n%u\n%4s\n%s\n",
        $time,
        strftime('%s, %F %T %Z',$time),
        gmstrftime('%s, %F %T %Z',$time) );
}

?>
```

## Wrong result

`%s` should return the original timestamp, but it does not. The results difference is 1 hour (3600 seconds).

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC')

1546303600
1546300000, 2019-01-01 00:46:40 UTC <<< WRONG!
1546300000, 2019-01-01 00:46:40 GMT <<< WRONG!

1556703600
1556700000, 2019-05-01 09:40:00 UTC <<< WRONG!
1556700000, 2019-05-01 09:40:00 GMT <<< WRONG!

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin')

1546303600
1546303600, 2019-01-01 01:46:40 CET
1546300000, 2019-01-01 00:46:40 GMT <<< WRONG!

1556703600
1556703600, 2019-05-01 11:40:00 CEST
1556700000, 2019-05-01 09:40:00 GMT <<< WRONG!
```

I reported the bug already to bugs.php.net: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77840

## Some Notes for clarification (edit)

PHP docu tells: "`%s` gives the same result as `time()`". And this result is independent of the timezone (seconds since epoch). So `strftime("%s",ANY_TIME)` must return `ANY_TIME`. Same for `gmstrftime()`.

Unix tool date works like expected:

```
date '+%s %F %T' -d@1556703600
date -u '+%s %F %T' -d@1556703600
TZ=UTC date '+%s %F %T' -d@1556703600
```

The result is:

```
1556703600 2019-05-01 11:40:00
1556703600 2019-05-01 09:40:00
1556703600 2019-05-01 09:40:00
```

So it is not an issue of the underlying C function!

Comment: I suspect this is down to `date_default_timezone_set` not working as you expect it to, rather than anything to do with `strftime`.

Comment: `%s` must give always the timestamp independent of the timezone. From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php : "%s : Unix Epoch Time timestamp (same as the time() function)"

Comment: An interesting side note, the use of `%s` by itself in `strftime` or `gmstrftime` on Windows results in no output at all making it real hard to test!

Answer (score 4):

The variance seems to be down to how the timezone is set. The following test will show you that strftime thinks there is a UTC offset no matter what is set using `date_default_timezone_set`.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo strftime("%s %z", 1546303600);
date_default_timezone_set("America/Vancouver");
echo strftime("%s %z", 1546303600);
```

[The code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1634) appears to apply an offset that's derived from the system timezone, so you could try this instead:

```
putenv("TZ=UTC");
echo strftime("%s %z", 1546303600);
```

And it should work. According to [the documentation they've provided](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), this definitely appears to be incorrect behaviour.

Comment: The php docu says, that `%s` returns the same as `time()`. And this is independent of the timeszone (the seconds since epoch). btw, Command line tool `date` works correct.

Comment: I added a bash/date example to proof, that it is not an issue of the underlying C function `strftime()`

Comment: I see what you're saying. Definitely a documentation problem at the least. The `%s` format isn't part of the [Open Group specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html) so there's no official word on how it should behave. [Looking at the code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1634), there are definitely offsets being applied in contradiction to what PHP documentation says.

Comment: Strange is, that gmstrftime() returns the wrong results too, even if it should work in UTC/GMT. So it is not an docu error, it is an implementation error.

Comment: Nosies on filing the bug report!